# How can I see all my updates on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

Does there exist a way to see all my updates on LinkedIn?

Comment: I don't find LinkedIn to be very user-friendly. Not being able to view all your posts (regardless of how old they are) is just one example of why....

Comment: Yes this is ridiculous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Activity Feed on Profile Page - No Longer Supported. 
What happened to the activity feed section on the profile page?](http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1602)

Last Reviewed: 12/16/2013

> At LinkedIn, we want to provide a great experience for members like you. So from time to time, we take a look at our features to evaluate how they're being used by our members. Part of this process sometimes means we decide to eliminate a feature, so we can better invest those resources in building new and better LinkedIn products.
>
> Starting in December, you will no longer see your activity feed on your LinkedIn profile, which shows your most recent site activity.
>
> Being able to share what you do on LinkedIn is important to us and we are working on more useful ways for you and other members to view and interact with your activity on LinkedIn from your profile. In the meantime, you can still access your own activity from the Homepage:
>
> 1. Click **Home** in the top left of your LinkedIn homepage.
> 2. Move your cursor over **All Updates**, found below the Share box and to the right.
> 3. Select **Your Updates**.
>
> You can also share updates to your network directly from the homepage, and you can have other activities broadcast to your network. Learn more about [showing or hiding your activity updates](http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/global/id/78/ft/eng).
>
> If you’d like to promote your interests and actions, we encourage you to update these sections of your profile:
>
> - The summary is an important section where you can tell your professional story: goals, objectives, background, interests and aspirations. If you don’t yet have a summary, you may add one:
>
>   - Move your cursor over **Profile** at the top of your homepage and select **Edit Profile**.
>   - Scroll down and click **+Add a Summary**. Then type in your text and click **Save**.
>   - Add visuals (photos, videos and presentations) to your summary, experience and education to show the projects or work that you directly impacted. [Learn how](http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/global/id/34325/ft/eng).
>
> **Note:** Unfortunately, the ability to filter your homepage feed to show only the activity of one member is not possible today.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though LinkedIn only maintains data about your updates for a couple weeks.  Please visit [this LinkedIn Community question](http://community.linkedin.com/questions/16044/how-to-see-my-update-history.html) to view more information.  You're also better off posting your updates to a blog to maintain **all** your updates.

If you are satisfied with viewing only a **limited** amount of updates...

1. Go to linkedin.com/updates (login as well)
2. And click on "Your Updates" in the tab pane.

Answer (score 1):

Now you click "Home"
Hover over "Profile"
Click "Your Updates"

Comment: Upvoted, but this does seem to only show activity in the last two weeks?

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like LinkedIn updated the flow for recent activity:

You can select [image]

then select [image]

now you can see the latest your activity.

Answer (score 0):

According to their [help page](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/49653/viewing-and-deleting-profile-activity-updates?lang=en), go to "View Profile" and click on "View all activities".

I didn't see "View all activities" but found "See all activities" under "Your Activity" section on the Profile page.